# How can i run Django channels on production?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, django-channels

I deployed a simple Django app to a VPS, here is my environment:

```
virtualenv
gunicorn
nginx
systemd
```

Everything works perfectly, i can see my template loading. I also added a small Django Channels feature, but that part doesn't work; so while i can use it on WSGI without any problem, if i try to reach a Consumer, i will get an error. So my question is: how can i run Channels too in production?

Here is what i currently did:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 54.39.20.155;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoom/WaitingRoom/static;
        }

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv.sock;
        }
    }
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoom
ExecStart=/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv.sock WR.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start gunicorn: `sudo systemctl start gunicorn`
To start nginx: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Answer (score 1):

To access channesl you need to run through a ASGI server like daphne (that ships with channels) instead of WSGI geunicorn you are using, see:

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html

to start the server `daphne -p 8001 myproject.asgi:application` then in your nginx you need to proxy pass to port 8001

Comment: Yes, but what i don't understand is: do i only need to edit my current nginx configuration (the first block of code i pasted here) or do i need to create a new one? Also, the daphne command you mentioned, shouldn't it be daemonized or something?

Comment: so you can have daphne server your entire application aka normal HTTP views and WS consumers.

Comment: `daphne command you mentioned, shouldn't it be daemonized or something?`, if you are running this directly yes just like your `gunicorn` one. but i would suggest (if your able) to deploy these things as docker containers.

Comment: if you dont want to run your full server through daphne then add a rout based path for your ws routs into your nginx so that those requets are routed to daphne.

Comment: Ok, so i do not need to create a new nginx file, just edit the new one? In this case what i don't understand is how am i supposed to edit the current one. Yes, i'm planning to use docker in the future, this is just a test to learn some deployment practices